# How to change VIEW size in MFC to fit the input image?

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to change the VIEW size to fit the size of an input image.

Firstly, I use File Open to open a bmp or jpg(jpeg/gif) image.

Open bmp image:

```
void CDrawToolView::ShowBitmap(CDC* pDC,CString strPicPath)
{        
    HBITMAP hBitmap=(HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,strPicPath,IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_CREATEDIBSECTION|LR_DEFAULTSIZE|LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    m_bitmap.Detach();
    m_bitmap.Attach(hBitmap);

    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);

    CDC dcImage;
    if (!dcImage.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC))
    {
        return;
    }
    BITMAP bm;
    m_bitmap.GetBitmap(&bm);
    dcImage.SelectObject(&m_bitmap);
    pDC->StretchBlt(0,0,rect.right,rect.bottom,&dcImage,0,0,bm.bmWidth,bm.bmHeight,SRCCOPY); 
}
```

Open jpg(jpeg/gif) image:

```
void CDrawToolView::ShowPic(CDC* pDC,CString strPicPath)
{        
    if(!m_MyImage.IsNull())
        m_MyImage.Destroy();
    HRESULT hResult=m_MyImage.Load(strPicPath);
    int iWidth=m_MyImage.GetWidth();
    int iHeight=m_MyImage.GetHeight();
    m_MyImage.Draw(pDC->m_hDC,0,0,iWidth,iHeight);
}
```

Then, I want to change `cs.cx` and `cs.cy` in `MainFrm.cpp` with the size of image.

My original VIEW setting is:

```
BOOL CMainFrame::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
    if( !CFrameWnd::PreCreateWindow(cs) )
        return FALSE;
    cs.x=320;
    cs.y=15;

    cs.cx=441; //210*2
    cs.cy=701; //297*2

    return TRUE;
}
```

Can I use pointer to pass the width and height of input image from `CDrawToolView` to the `cs.cx` and `cs.cy` in `MainFrm.cpp` , and automatically change the VIEW size?

**EDIT：**

I try to use `OnSize` to send back `cx` and `cy`:

```
void CDrawToolView::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CView::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);
    CWnd* pMainFrame = this->GetParent();
    ::SendMessage(pMainFrame->m_hWnd,WM_SIZE,0,0);
}
```

And how to pass the width and height to it?

Comment: Send an WM_SIZE message to your main frame.  But you'll need to compute the size necessary for it to be to wrap around the size of the bitmap image (i.e. you want the client space to be the size of the image, and you'll need to add the borders/frame size because the message requires the frame-size.

Comment: An easy way to do this is to get the current size of the client rect, determine how much you need to change that in order to achieve the size of your image, then get the current frame size, and send a WM_SIZE with a new rectangle that is adjusted by the adjustment-size you computed, above.  Simple :)

Comment: @Mordachai I have edited my question with your suggestion. And how to pass width and height to cx and cy?

Comment: Reading your question and edited part again, it doesn't really make sense. You seem to be having trouble understanding how to pass parameters in C (and C++) rather than a particular problem with MFC.

Comment: See IInspectable's answer.  If you know the size before showing the view, then that's a great approach.  If you load an image on the fly, and need to keep changing view-size to accommodate each newly loaded image, then you send to yourself a WM_SIZE message - you don't need an OnSize handler (that's quite irrelevant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To adjust the desired window dimensions to a specific client size before the window is created you need to call [`AdjustWindowRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632665.aspx) or [`AdjustWindowRectEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632667.aspx).

From the documentation:

> Calculates the required size of the window rectangle, based on the desired size of the client rectangle.

The required window styles and extended window styles are available through the [`CREATESTRUCT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632603.aspx) members `style` and `dwExStyle`.

Comment: I finally use `SetWindowPos()` to solve the problem. However, thank you indeed for your advice. I am a new comer in MFC and struggling with passing parameters in different situations. So I decide to learn from the basic as your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: Untested code - some of it is pseudo-code, but it should give you the IDEA:

```
inline BOOL MoveWindow(HWND hwnd, const RECT & rect, BOOL bRepaint)
{
    return ::MoveWindow(hwnd, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, bRepaint);
}

void CDrawToolView::LoadPic(CString strPicPath)
{        
    if(!m_MyImage.IsNull())
        m_MyImage.Destroy();
    HRESULT hResult=m_MyImage.Load(strPicPath);
    int iWidth=m_MyImage.GetWidth();
    int iHeight=m_MyImage.GetHeight();
    CRect client(0, 0, iWidth, iHeight);
    AdjustWindowRect(&client, GetWindowStyle(GetHwnd()), TRUE/FALSE); // You will need to write the helper: GetWindowStyle, or replace this with more statements to obtain the style into a DWORD and then use that DWORD here...
    ResizeWindow(GetHwnd(), &client, TRUE);
}
```